# Plot two different color of mapview pin

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I'm trying to display mapview with an array of coordinates. So, i load the latitudes and longitudes from array where those are contains. It is showing perfectly. Now, i want to display one paritcular latitude & longitude with different color pin. I've referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10900277) no such different i can't see.

ViewController.m

---

```
-(void)showMap:
{
...
...
DataProvider *d = [DataProvider getInstance];
NSInteger numb = sender.view.tag;
d.colorlatitude = [[arraxy objectAtIndex:numb] objectForKey:@"lat"];
d.colorlongitude = [[arraxy objectAtIndex:numb] objectForKey:@"lng"];
[d._address removeAllObjects];
[arraxy removeObjectAtIndex:sender.view.tag];
d._address = arraxy;

MapViewController *map = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];

}
```

MapViewController.m

---

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
DataProvider *d = [DataProvider getInstance];
[_mapView removeAnnotations:_mapView.annotations];

RegisterViewController *appDelegate = [[RegisterViewController alloc]init];

[_mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[_mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([appDelegate.locationManager location].coordinate, 1000, 1000)];
[_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];

MKCoordinateRegion rregion = {{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
rregion.center.latitude = [d.colorlatitude floatValue];
rregion.center.longitude = [d.colorlongitude floatValue];
rregion.span.latitudeDelta=0.001f;
rregion.span.longitudeDelta=0.001f;
[_mapView setRegion:rregion];

MapviewAnnotations *add = [[MapviewAnnotations alloc]init];
add.coordinate = rregion.center;
[_mapView addAnnotation:add];


if (d._address)
{
    for (int i=0; i<[d._address count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dic=[d._address objectAtIndex:i];
        MKCoordinateRegion region={{0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.0}};
        region.center.latitude=[[dic objectForKey:@"lat"]floatValue];
        region.center.longitude=[[dic objectForKey:@"lng"]floatValue];
        region.span.latitudeDelta=0.001f;
        region.span.longitudeDelta=0.001f;
        [_mapView setRegion:region];

        MapviewAnnotations *ann=[[MapviewAnnotations alloc]init];
        ann.coordinate=region.center;
        [_mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }
}
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

and my `MKMapView`'s delegate method is

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MapviewAnnotations class]])
{
    return nil;
}

static NSString *reuseId = @"currentloc";

MKPinAnnotationView *annView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
if (annView == nil)
{
    annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
    annView.animatesDrop = NO;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
}
else
{
    annView.annotation = annotation;
}

DataProvider *mvAnn = [DataProvider getInstance];
if (mvAnn.colorlatitude) // here i'm checking the condition.
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}
else
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}

return annView;
}
```

I'm just writting the condition if the co-ordinate is there i've to plot the green color pin to that particular coordinate only. How to achieve this?

Comment: you can use pin image

[annView setImageName:@"pin-green.png"];

Comment: @Pratik I tried it. Its working. But, i want to show that into particular latitude & longtitude's coordinate.

Comment: ya but use two different color pins one os red and one is green and put in to if else condition

Comment: @Pratik I've tried. It simply append green color only..

Comment: means is there drops only green color pins not red?

Comment: @Pratik Only green color pins..

Comment: then check your condition first. it is working or not

Comment: refer this link, if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898122/map-view-annotations-with-different-pin-colors?lq=1

Comment: @HinataHyuga I used that answer only. No such different there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this through some flags like below inside of my `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id  <MKAnnotation>)annotation`

```
MapviewAnnotations *mvAnn = (MapviewAnnotations *)annotation;
if (mvAnn.flag == 1)
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}
else if (mvAnn.flag == 10)
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
else
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}
```

In my viewWillAppear i received the coordinates from `DataProvider` and assigned with separate `MapviewAnnotations` with flags and differentiate it with three type of pins simply.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your code and the one Hinata has referred you to is that the if statement in the other code uses a value (`yesno`) on the annotation it is currently drawing to decide what colour to use. You are getting a value from `DataProvider` but not telling it which annotation you are drawing, so the instance it gives you is just what ever the `instance` method feels like returning at the time the map is asking for the pin. You need to tell it what you're drawing for it to decide what to put into `colorlatitude`